# How would you make this unit testable?

Tags: c#

I originally posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402843/how-to-unit-test-static-readonly-httpclient?noredirect=1#comment134733025_76402843), but was told a code review was needed first.

This class is used to call an API that creates/updates groups in an Identity Provider.

I'd like to unit test the following class.

How can I mock the `HttpClient` when it's used as a `static readonly` field in a static class?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests) doesn't help as the OP is using an instance field for the `HttpClient`.

Here's my class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Integration.IdentityProvider
{
    public static class IdentityProviderApiCaller
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

        static IdentityProviderApiCaller()
        {
            HttpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create();
            HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someApi.com");
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        }

        public static async Task<IList<AddGroupResult>> AddGroups(AddGroup[] addGroupsModel)
        {
            var content = GetContent(addGroupsModel);
            var urlPath = "/groups";

            var result = await HttpClient.PutAsync(urlPath, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return await GetObject<IList<AddGroupResult>>(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static async Task<T> GetObject<T>(HttpResponseMessage result) where T : class
        {
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await DeserializeObject<T>(result.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            var errorResult = await DeserializeObject<ErrorResult>(result.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            throw new Exception(errorResult.ExceptionMessage);
        }

        private static async Task<T> DeserializeObject<T>(HttpContent content) where T : class
        {
            var jsonContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            T obj;
            try
            {
                obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult<T>(null).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        private static StringContent GetContent<T>(T obj)
        {
            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return content;
        }
    }

    public class AddGroup
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddGroupResult
    {
        public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    }

    public class ErrorResult
    {
        public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer, you can't "unit test" this unless you're willing to inject the HttpClient instance. The link you've provided details passing through a mocked instance of a HttpMessageHandler, which would allow you to intercept http requests and response with a fake http response.

Comment: What we do on code review is look at working code from your project and make insightful observations about the code. We do not answer how to questions here. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a way to improve the code so it can be easily unit-tested, I've made the suggestions in the original StackOverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416457/706456.

Comment: @oleksii The OP's question was specifically "How can I mock the HttpClient when it's used as a static readonly field in a static class?" which is outside the scope of code review. That to me is a valid question on stackoverflow, not code review.